# Connect Github using OAuth in javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth, github-api

Is it possible to connect with Github using oAuth in JAVASCRIPT/AJAX/JQuery

I have came across with its implementation in php and node.js, but i need to have it in js.
Is it possible. Any links?

As per http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/ , i'm not able to implement it in js.

Here is the link for implementation in php, please help me out to implement the same in js/ajax/jquery.

Thanks

Comment: Some of the javascript libraries might support it http://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/#javascript

Comment: If you are thinking of a pure client side JavaScript solution (within a Web browser exclusively) - no, it's not possible. You have to have a server side to do that.

Comment: you mean node.js, for js

Comment: What have you actually tried?

Comment: Finally i Used xhr AJAX call by giving params `username` and `password` in header of that request.

Answer (score 2):

I was just searching for the same issue myself and apparently
it is not possible. what you requested is referred to as [Implicit grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-30#section-1.3.2) and the [link](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorization-options-for-oauth-apps/) you provided for Github api states that:

> The implicit grant type is not supported

You can still access it using cors or jsonp which are both mentioned as methods to use Github api ([json-p](https://developer.github.com/v3/#json-p-callbacks), [cors](https://developer.github.com/v3/#cross-origin-resource-sharing)) but unless you are authenticated the rate limit is bounded to 60 requests per hour https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting

Edit:

So I did some further reading, if you want to use their api with a web browser script you can create yourself a [Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens), and define it's scope as [no scope](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps/). This will make sure it will have only read access to your public information. Thus you could use this token without fearing having it published publicly in a website and someone abusing it.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use 'Javascript-only to connect to Github, or any other OAuth provider that does not support OAuth2 'implicit' grant type/flow, and you do not mind using an OAuth-based web service, which greatly simplifies everything to a < 10 lines, you can try to use OAuth.io (https://oauth.io).

OAuth.io provides an open-source Javascript library: https://cdn.rawgit.com/oauth-io/oauth-js/c5af4519/dist/oauth.js. The library communicates with the OAuth.io server, which is configured with your Github (OAuth server) client id/client secret, so it acts as a intermediary between your browser, and Github (or any OAuth provider), making it capable of completing the OAuth2 'authorization code' grant type/flow.

The code then is as simple as:

```
  OAuth.popup('github').then(github => {
    console.log('github:', github);
    // You can use the github object to 
    // perform any HTTP get/post to Github API endpoints
    github.get('/user').then(data => {
      console.log('self data:', data);
    })
  });
```

Reference: https://coderwall.com/p/sjbwcq/javascript-github-social-login-button-for-oauth

Answer (score 1):

No, for security reasons you cannot login with client-side code only. This is to protect the client-secret code.

You can create a simple server-side app that protects your codes. For example, have a look at https://github.com/prose/gatekeeper

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and made a Netlify Function to handle the backend so it would be serverless.

Here's the repo: https://github.com/cadbox1/github-oktokit-oauth-netlify